# Ext js 6 filtering Tree Panel

Tags: extjs

help me understand the tree filtering.

I have input ow

```
xtype: 'triggerfield',
    listeners: {
        change: function() {
        console.log()
    }
}
```

How can I filter the tree? I need to send a request to the server with a value from the field

Comment: Have you tried treestore's [filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.TreeStore.html#method-filter) method?

Comment: I've watched, but I still can not figure out how the framework works @scebotari66

Comment: If you want to make a request to the server on filter, your treestore must have the `removeFilter` config set to `true`.

Comment: @АлександрКотов Where is your tree? Where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **filterBy** method to do simple or complex filtering on TreeStore:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoload: true,
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        specialProp: 1,
        children: [{
            text: "detention",
            leaf: true,
            specialProp: 1
        }, {
            text: "homework",
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                text: "book report",
                leaf: true,
                specialProp: 1
            }, {
                text: "algebra",
                leaf: true,
                specialProp: 2
            }]
        }, {
            text: "buy lottery tickets",
            leaf: true,
            specialProp: 1
        }]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            id: 'treePanelId',
            store: store,
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'specialProp=1 Filter',
                    handler: function () {
                        var treePanel = Ext.getCmp('treePanelId');
                        treePanel.getStore().filterBy(function (item) {
                            if (item.get('root') === true) return true;
                            else if (item.get('specialProp') === 1) return true;
                            else return false;
                        });
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Clear filter',
                    handler: function () {
                        var treePanel = Ext.getCmp('treePanelId');
                        treePanel.getStore().clearFilter();
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

**Example Fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29si

**EDIT:**

**For remote filtering you can do it like following**:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    remoteFilter: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    root: {
        expanded: true
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            id: 'treePanelId',
            store: store,
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'specialProp=1 Filter',
                    handler: function () {
                        var treePanel = Ext.getCmp('treePanelId');
                        treePanel.getStore().filter('specialProp', 1);
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Clear filter',
                    handler: function () {
                        var treePanel = Ext.getCmp('treePanelId');
                        treePanel.getStore().clearFilter();
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

**Remote Sort Fiddle Example:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29sq

Take a look at response of request, you can filter on server side with this. Also for ease of understanding I have put params in response to show how filters would be actually appear on http request which need to be processed.

**Note:** Make sure you send data response in following format:

> {    status: 'success',    children: [{...}, {...}, ....] }

If you are sending response in other format you will need to process it in store proxy.

Comment: How much I realized this is a local filtering? I need to send a request to the server. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @АлександрКотов Answer is edited to show remote filtering along with new fiddle.